# While scrolling, the uitableview cells on which the data was first set would be repeated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, chat, reload

We are creating a chat app. There is a uitableview on the chat screen. Every time we scroll to uitableview, data is being set from the array in cellForRowAt. Images, audio are loading again and video also. I want that once the data is set on the cell it will not be reset like WhatsApp.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    let cell:GroupsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GroupsTableViewCell") as! GroupsTableViewCell
    
    let user: Groupslist
    user = GroupList[indexPath.row]
    cell.lbl_name_group.text = user.name;
cell.img_group.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: user.group_image!)
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You need put some code. 
The default behavior of a cell is to be created / allocated when it will appear on the screen (when the user scrolls the table) and to be deallocated when it leaves the screen. This is done to optimize the memory usage of the device. Imagine you have 100 allocated cells in memory, each with a video.

Comment: Please update your question with your datasource methods.

Comment: @PhillipMills question updated datasource code

Comment: Cells are just for display, not for data storage, so you have your own data cache.  That looks reasonable.  Is there an actual problem in how it's working?

Comment: what do you mean by data cache?